# How to create mode_rewrite rule on Apache Server FreeBSD 8.1

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, freebsd, bsd

I'm Working on a server running apache version 2.2.25 on FreeBSD 8.1.
Lets say I have the the following url: **this.domain.com/html/folder/index.php**
And I want to rewrite it as this: **this.domain.com/index**

How specifically would I create the rewrite rule? Should I create the rewrite rule in the httpd.conf file or the .htaccess file, or does it not really matter?
Also, is there a way to change the domain name "this.domain.com" to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want users to enter the shorter url `this.domain.com/index` and serve the php at `this.domain.com/html/folder/index.php`; add the following rules to the `.htaccess` at root `/`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^this\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ html/folder/$1.php [L]
```

I'm not sure what you mean by changing your domain to something else. `this.domain.com` can be changed to `that.domain.com` or `addon-domain.com` but would make sense only if their DNS point to the same server (to serve  shared content). Otherwise, it's like an external redirect to some other site.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^this\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://that.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/index$ /html/folder/index.php [PT]
```